# Shooting automatically in a Shooter Game (Swift 4 - SpriteKit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, skaction

I'm working on a game project with Xcode. 
I've written the code that makes the ship shoot the projectiles, but I don't know what function to use to make the ship shoot automatically.

Could you help me? Thank you in advance!

Here's my code, from the GameScene :

```
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let projectile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "projectile")
    projectile.zPosition = 1
    projectile.position = CGPoint(x: player.position.x, y: player.position.y)

    projectile.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: projectile.size.width/2)
    projectile.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    projectile.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Projectile
    projectile.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster
    projectile.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    projectile.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    self.addChild(projectile)
    let action = SKAction.moveTo(x: self.frame.width + projectile.size.width, duration: 0.5)

    projectile.run(action, completion: {
        projectile.removeAllActions()
        projectile.removeFromParent()
    })

}
```

Comment: On touches began you can call a function to begin shooting and repeat it every 0.x seconds. On touched ended you can invalidate the timer. First is move the projectile code into its own function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a comment by Jake I am assuming that you want the ship to fire "automatically" not repeating while holding the finger down.

You can use the update func to control the automatic shooting. in my example the update command fires every 1 second

```
private var updateTime: Double = 0

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    if updateTime == 0 {
        updateTime = currentTime
    }

    if currentTime - updateTime > 1 {
        self.shoot()
        updateTime = currentTime
    }
}

func shoot() {

    let projectile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "projectile")
    projectile.zPosition = 1
    projectile.position = CGPoint(x: player.position.x, y: player.position.y)

    projectile.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: projectile.size.width/2)
    projectile.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    projectile.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Projectile
    projectile.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster
    projectile.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    projectile.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    self.addChild(projectile)
    let action = SKAction.moveTo(x: self.frame.width + projectile.size.width, duration: 0.5)

    projectile.run(action, completion: {
        projectile.removeAllActions()
        projectile.removeFromParent()
    })
}
```

Comment: you're welcome. Please mark this answer as correct then so that others may benefit from this question